# C# Same select between two listbox

Tags: c#, select, listbox

I have a probeleme with my code. I want have the same select between two listbox, but i have stackoverflow error, i understand my error but I don't find a solution. Someone can help me ?

```
    private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int i = 0;
        while(i<listBox1.Items.Count)
        {
                listBox2.SetSelected(i, listBox1.GetSelected(i));
                i++;
        }
    }

    private void listBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int i = 0;
        while (i < listBox2.Items.Count)
        {
            listBox1.SetSelected(i, listBox2.GetSelected(i));
            i++;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please include the error in your question

Comment: A simple boolean can do the job

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could remove the event handler before setting the selected indexes and then add the event handler again.

```
private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int i = 0;
    listBox2.SelectedIndexChanged -= listBox2_SelectedIndexChanged;
    while (i < listBox1.Items.Count)
    {
        listBox2.SetSelected(i, listBox1.GetSelected(i));
        i++;
    }
    listBox2.SelectedIndexChanged += listBox2_SelectedIndexChanged;
}

private void listBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int i = 0;
    listBox1.SelectedIndexChanged -= listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged;
    while (i < listBox2.Items.Count)
    {
        listBox1.SetSelected(i, listBox2.GetSelected(i));
        i++;
    }
    listBox1.SelectedIndexChanged += listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged;
}
```